# Qt Creator environment variable: executing from QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is there any Qt variable which can be used to determine whether if the code is being run from QtCreator (e.g. by pressing CTRL+R) or from outside (e.g. from terminal)? Or do I have to add a "custom" environment variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to know that? Can't you just set an environment variable when running from Creator? (See the Projects pane, Run tab)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I can of course set environment variables, but I was wondering if there is already one macro/variable doing that.

Comment: if for debugging purposes then there is the DEBUG macro (or similar). it doesn't specify that it is run from QtCreator but that it isn't your release build

Comment: An alternative method to determine what has launched your program would be to look at its parent process. If it's running via Qt Creator, that will be the parent process along with its pid.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a commandline argument when th application is started from Qt creator. You can add one argument in the Qt Creator Run Settings like "Creator"

In Your application you can check if it is run from Qt Creator or not by:

```
QStringList arguments = qApp->arguments();
if(arguments[1]=="Creator")
{
    qDebug()<<"It is run From Qt Creator";
}
```

Since the first argument is name of the program, you should check the second one.